# FastMM reports memory leaks on STL containers in C++ Builder 6

Tags: c++, stl, c++builder, c++builder-6, fastmm

When I create an empty console application and use an STL container in it, FastMM reports a memory leak when the application is closed.

For example, if I create a `std::vector<int>` in `main()`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

Compile, run and close, no leaks are reported.

If I do:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(100);
```

I get:

> This application has leaked memory. The small block leaks are:
>
> 309 - 340 bytes: Unknown x 1

Similarly, I get a leak reported on:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(100);
v.clear();
```

And also a leak is reported on:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(1);
```

For some containers, like `std::deque`, its enough just to create one, and even without altering its content a leak is reported when the application is closed.

Can anyone explain what is happening? I use Borland C++Builder 6 and FastMM4. I've been changing various settings in `FastMMOptions.inc`, however I'm still seeing these leaks reported.

Comment: [Borland C++Builder 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder#Version_history) appears to have come out in 2002.... any chance you could use a more modern compiler? Even a more recent version of C++Builder? 14 years is a long time in software terms.

Comment: I say that because given that snippet of code, there is nothing that would cause a memory leak (without seeing the surrounding context) other than a faulty `std::vector` implementation by the compiler. Or a false positive reported by the leak detector.

Comment: Yes we have Borland XE7 and new projects are developed in new environment. However I need to investigate memory leaks in existing projects, which we haven't migrated to XE7 yet due to their size. I find the FastMM very useful, but because the STL is used at many places in our code, it is pointing out the leaks that confuse me very much.

Comment: @CoryKramer: sometimes people don't have the option of using a modern compiler.  I myself still use C++Builder 6 at my day job. Not because I want to, but because my company requires it (and not from a lack of trying to upgrade over the years, the PTBs would not allow it because newer versions were more unstable and did not satisfy business requirements).

Comment: `std::deque` in C++Builder 6 is bugged and unusable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing a `std::vector` does not deallocate the memory used for the `vector`'s internal array, it merely destructs the items inside the array and then sets the `std::vector::size()` to 0. The array itself is still allocated so it can be reused for new items pushed in the `vector`.  The `vector`'s destructor will deallocate the array.

In C++Builder 6, the default STL library is STLPort (replaced with Dinkumware in C++Builder 2006).  STLPort's implementation of the `~std::vector()` merely destructs the array items (as if `clear()` has been called) but does not deallocate the array itself, thus the "leak" you are seeing.  Which is not actually a leak at all, according to the following FAQ on the STLPort website:

[Q6.2 My tool detect memory leaks in application with STLport. Is this leak from STLport?](http://stlport.sourceforge.net/FAQ.shtml#leaks)

> A6.2 In most cases this are 'pseudo memory leaks' that some tools wrongly supports.
>
> **In the default compile of STLport, the node allocator is used to allocate internal memory. The node allocator works by pre-allocating a large chunk of memory and handing out small memory blocks out. The memory chunk is not freed during running an application that uses STLport** (i.e. it don't returned to system, There are tools like BoundsChecker, Purify or Valgrind that check for memorytml leaks, for memory that isn't freed when no longer used. **These tools may report false memory leaks when one uses STLport's node allocator. The memory chunk is normally freed at application end, but the memory checkers usually report memory leaks before that point**. Another memory problem might be reported when you use shared libraries (e.g. DLL, this problem specific for Windows DLL model) that uses STLport internally and are statically link to it. If memory is allocated in a dll and released in an other then the STLport node allocator will keep the released memory for a future use. If you do not use this memory then your application global memory consumtion will grow until the appli crash even if there is no realy memory leak. This is why you should always use a coherent configuration everything in dll or everything in static lib.
>
> There are ways to remove the pseudo memory leaks (since the memory is properly freed at the end of the program, the leaks are just pseudo-ones). You could use another allocator that is used in STLport. Open the file `"stlport/stl/_site_config.h"` and uncomment either one of the following:
>
> ```
> _STLP_USE_NEWALLOC   enables a simple allocator that uses "new/delete"
> _STLP_USE_MALLOC     enables a simple allocator that uses "malloc/free"
> ```
>
> The new/delete allocator has the advantage of giving an entry point to track memory starvation, see set_new_handler in your compiler doc or the C++ Standard for more information.
>
> Alternatively you can define the following symbol, just uncomment it in `"stlport/stl/_site_config.h"`.
>
> ```
> _STLP_LEAKS_PEDANTIC
> ```
>
> The symbol forces freeing all memory chunks. Also see the comments around the symbol in the config file.
>
> Note that you have to recompile STLport AND your application and all of your dependent libraries if you make any change to the file!
>
> There are also some defines that help in debugging memory problems in STLport. In _STLP_DEBUG mode, just also define the following symbols, either in "./stlport/stl_user_config.h" or in your project settings:
>
> ```
> _STLP_DEBUG_ALLOC
> _STLP_DEBUG_UNINITIALIZED
> ```
>
> You don't need to rebuild STLport for these options, but you have to rebuild your application and all of your dependent libraries if you make any change to the file.

That said, the RogueWave STL, which was used in earlier C++Builder versions, is also shipped with C++Builder 6 for backwards compatibility with older code, and does not suffer from this issue.  You can switch from STLPort to RogueWave by defining `_USE_OLD_RW_STL` in your project's conditionals list.

Comment: Excellent, and very informative reply. With `_USE_OLD_RW_STL` defined, FastMM does not report any leaks on the containers used in our project (`std::vector` `std::list` `std::deque`). Thank you very much. It is so much easier to go through the memory leaks report now.

Comment: One other thing I noticed, any usage of `std::cout` reports a leak too. Luckily there are not many in our code, but if you know another 'magic conditional define' to stop those showing up in report that would be great. Example: `std::cout << "hello" << endl;` reports:
 13 - 20 bytes: Unknown x 1
 21 - 36 bytes: std::codecvt<char,char,std::mbstate_t> x 1, Unknown x 2
 37 - 52 bytes: Unknown x 2
 53 - 68 bytes: std::ctype<char> x 1, __rwstd::locale_imp x 2
 85 - 100 bytes: Unknown x 2
 485 - 532 bytes: Unknown x 3
, while `printf("hello\n");` reports no leak